# angular2 dynamic height for the children elements

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

```
   @Component({
    selector: 'sc',
    templateUrl: '<div>
<form id="frmId" #cntfrm [formGroup]="scForm">

</form>
<div id="boxId" [style.height.px]= "cntfrm.clientHeight">
</div>
</div>
',
    directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class SCComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
.......
}
```

I need to set the height of the form which may vary from the div height when the `sc` component is initialized. I tried the above approach of `cntfrm` reference variable height to div height, but it's ignored. But I can display value of `{{cntfrm.clientHeight}}` using interpolation on the UI.

Comment: Do you get an error in the console?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> ngAfterViewChecked(){
>
>     setTimeout(()=>{ this.height = this.el.getElementsByClassName("form")[0].clientHeight;}, 0); 
>  }
> ```

https://plnkr.co/edit/VdRKuQwDyzFX9VMZSK1J

Actually issue is my form is template bounded using ngif. So form is not rendered  untill  ngAfterView. If i assign form height in ngOnInit, I get undefined error. If I assign it normally in ngAfterView, I get angular unidirectional error as the state is changed after the view is composed. So, I have do it in next cycle using setinterval. Other option is enable production mode. I guess in that mode, angular change detection parses two times for each event loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, maybe you can try something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.height = document.getElementById('frmId').clientHeight;
}
```

### EDIT

Created a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/y6ZG7uI5fLhAzqiY8s2t

Comment: I tried this.formHeight = this.cntfrm.nativeElement.clientHeight in ngAfterViewInit(). I used @ViewChild('cntfrm') cntfrm: ElementRef;
 to get cntfrm reference. But I get ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedException.BaseException. This is due to angular2 unidirectional change detection policy. I can avoid it in prod mode. But there should be better way to handle simple syncing of heights of two child elements.

Comment: It would be better to get the element ref using `@ViewChild('cntfrm' {read: ElementRef}) form:ElementRef;` instead of `document.getElementById(...)`. `ngOnInit()` is also the wrong method for this code. It should be `ngAfterViewInit()` to ensure the DOM is actually built.